# One or more data sources is missing credentials

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc, credentials

I am implementing a series of rdlc reports on a webpage using a ReportViewer.  When the report is initially generated is works fine but when I try to change the page of the report the following error is displayed:

**"One or more data sources is missing credentials"**

I have checked that the Data Source of the Local report is set correctly and the fact that the first page of the report is correctly displayed is proof of this.

When I export the report to a PDF or any other format it correctly includes all the report pages.

I have also tried implementing the PageNavigation event but this error is thrown before the event is called.

Does any one have any incite into this issue and what solution there may be?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the the problem.  I had a setting AsyncRendering set to false in order enable the reportviewer to stretch to the full width of the page.

Unfortunately this causes a postback and the enitre page is reloaded and obviously the datasource is lost.

Unfortunate as I will now have to manage the width of the reportviewer manually and it does not look great.

Anyway solution is to ensure AsyncRendering = true.